# Getting CollectionViewContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to get `CollectionViewContentSize` as done in apple's Photo objective C implementation. Below is the codes

Apple's Code

```
 CGSize cellSize = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout).itemSize;
```

My Code

```
 let cellSize: CGSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.collectionViewContentSize(self.collectionViewLayout)
```

And I get an error saying `(UICollectionViewLayout) -> 'is not convertible to 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout -> () -> CGSize'`

Comment: Did you tried `collectionView.contentSize` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy:
self.collectionViewLayout return `UICollectionViewLayout` type not `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, so you should cast it:

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let cellSize: CGSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.collectionViewContentSize(layout)()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjC

```
  CGSize cellSize = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout).itemSize;
```

Swift

```
  let cellSize: CGSize = self.collectionViewLayout.itemSize
```